# Was the korban pesach eaten only when satiated?

Tags: halacha, passover, eating, korban, maseches-pesachim

Kohanim were to eat kobanot only when satiated.  Does that apply to the korban pesach?  Was the korban pesach eaten only when satiated?

Comment: Please source your first sentence.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Yehuda. As @DoubleAA indicated, please [edit] in a source for your first sentence.

Comment: @DoubleAA In support of the first sentence: "This is why Pesach and Kodshim are eaten after satiation." http://www.dafyomi.co.il/horayos/halachah/ho-hl-010.htm  and " Pesach is eaten (l'Chatchilah) when satiated, i.e. but he has a little appetite. Also, we can say that one who ate Korban Pesach Achilah Gasah fulfilled Pesach (i.e. he owned a share of a Korban Pesach, and he could have eaten it at night), even though he did not fulfill the Mitzvah of eating Pesach, for eating is not Me'akev." from the same source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rambam says in Hilchot Korbon Pesach, Chapter 8, Law 3:

> ג. מצוה מן המובחר לאכול בשר הפסח אכילת שובע לפיכך אם הקריב שלמי חגיגה בארבעה עשר אוכל מהן תחילה ואח"כ אוכל בשר הפסח כדי לשבוע ממנו ואם לא אכל אלא כזית יצא ידי חובתו וכן אכילת בשר פסח שני בלילי חמשה עשר לחדש אייר מצות עשה שנאמר בו על מצות ומרורים יאכלוהו:
>
> Halacha 3
>   The optimum manner of performing the mitzvah is to partake of the Paschal sacrifice when one is already sated. Therefore if one sacrificed festive peace-offerings on the fourteenth of Nisan, one should partake of them first and then partake of the meat of the Paschal sacrifice to be satiated from the festive offering. Even if one does not eat more than an olive-size portion, he fulfills his obligation.
>   Similarly, partaking of the second Paschal sacrifice on the fifteenth of the month of Iyar is a positive commandment, as stated: "Eat it with matzot and bitter herbs."