# Why is it forbidden to eat after the Qorban Pesah?

Tags: passover, korban, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, maseches-pesachim

The Mishnah (Pesahim 10:8) states ([Hebrew](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99_%D7%97), [English](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Pesachim.10.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> אין מפטירין אחר הפסח אפיקומן
>
> They may not add an afikoman after the Pesach offering.

The commentators (e.g. Bartenura) explain that this is to ensure the taste of the Qorban Pesah remains on one's palate.

Why is it important for the taste of the Qorban Pesah to remain on one's palate?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53023/was-the-korban-pesach-eaten-only-when-satiated

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71538/why-eat-korbanot-satiated